# Integer matrix visualization in Julia

Tags: matrix, julia, visualization

How to convert a random integer matrix into an image with colored grids?

I tried to using `convert(Image, rand(Int,3,3))` after viewing a [tutorial for Juno-LT](https://github.com/JuliaIDE/Juno-LT/blob/master/tutorial.jl#L129), but I got

```
julia> using Images
julia> convert(Image, rand(Int,3,3))
ERROR: UndefVarError: Image not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial you gave a link to is quite old. In `Images.jl`, images are simply arrays. There is no constructor with the name `Image` anymore.

```
using Images, ImageView
# this will show an image in which the highest value
# of the array is white and the lowest is black 
imshow(rand(Int, 3, 3))
```

It is better to take a look at [the official documentation](https://juliaimages.org/latest) of the packages of [JuliaImages](https://github.com/JuliaImages), specifically, the section [Arrays, Numbers and Colors](https://juliaimages.org/latest/arrays_colors/#Arrays,-Numbers,-and-Colors-1).